Probability inclusion-exclusion
Suppose we have $f:G\to H$ group homorphism if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).$ And let $h:G\to H$ be another group homorphism closed to $f,$
then we have $$\mathcal{P}(f(x+y)-f(y)\neq h(x+y) -h(y))=\mathcal{P}(f(x+y)\neq h(x+y) )+\mathcal{P}(f(y)\neq h(y))-\mathcal{P}((f(x+y)\neq h(x+y))\cap(f(y)\neq h(y) )).$$
My teacher uses this inclusion-exclusion property of probability in some places, how is this true? Anyone give me the intuition what is happening here.

Too long for a comment, but are you sure the statement is true?
It would be easier to consider its complementary form:
\begin{align*}
& - P(f(x + y) - f(y) = h(x + y) - h(y)) \\
=& -P(f(x + y) = h(x + y)) - P(f(y) = h(y)) + P(\{f(x + y) = h(x + y)\} \cup \{f(y) = h(y)\}). 
\end{align*}
Now using the homomorphism condition and rearranging terms shows that the above identity is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
& P(\{f(x + y) = h(x + y)\} \cup \{f(y) = h(y)\}) \\ 
=& P(f(x + y) = h(x + y)) + P(f(y) = h(y)) - P(f(x) = h(x)). 
\end{align*}
By the inclusion-exclusion formula, it is true if and only if
\begin{align*}
P(\{f(x + y) = h(x + y)\} \cap \{f(y) = h(y)\}) = P(f(x) = h(x)). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
$\eqref{1}$ is true if and only if (by the the homomorphism condition)
\begin{align*}
P(f(x) = h(x), f(y) = h(y)) = P(f(x) = h(x)).
\end{align*}
But normally we can only claim the left hand side probability is bounded above by the right hand side, rather than an identity.

Why you consider $-$ in complementary form?

@David "1"s are cancelled from each side of your "equation".

I don't understand your inclusion-exclusion formula.would you expand more.

@David Just take $A = {f(x + y) = h(x + y)}, B = {f(y) = h(y)}$ in the inclusion-exclusion formula $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Would you explain the homomorphism condition?
\begin{align*}
P(f(x) = h(x), f(y) = h(y)) = P(f(x) = h(x)).
\end{align*}, the intersection should be $ f(y) =f(y)? $

Sorry for typo, It should be $f(y)=h(y)?$

@David Substitute the definition of homomorphism into the left hand side of $(1)$, the event reduces to ${f(x) + f(y) = h(x) + h(y)}\cap{f(y) = h(y)}$, which is (trivially) ${f(x) = h(x)}\cap{f(y) = h(y)}$.  When you claimed it is ${f(y) = h(y)}$, how did you dispose ${f(x) = h(x)}$?
